# unsigned long ints multiplication

Tags: c, public-key-encryption

I am creating a public key generator and I do c= p*q; Where p and q are large prime numbers, but I keep getting this for C  11875820813;

```
long unsigned int c= p*q;
printf("C is: %d\n", c);
```

I know I has something to do with my numbers, but I don't know how to fix this.

I am trying to multiply:

872017*533297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overflowing the value. Remember that on a 32-bit platform an `unsigned long` can be at most a little over 4 billion.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit unsigned long max value is 4294967295.
Your multiplication is 465044050049 which overflows the unsigned long.

```
4294967295 (ULONG_MAX)
  <
465044050049 (your result)
  <
18446744073709551615 (ULONG_LONG_MAX)
```

You'll need to use an unsigned long long (64-bit unsigned integer type) (supposing your system supports them, which all modern systems do)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do public key cryptography using only the built in integer types of C, regardless of platform. Contemporary cryptography deals with numbers that are at least 1024 bits wide, which, if implemented in software, requires libraries that support such large values.